# Lightsail custom dns

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I have a simple website that  I wanted to be on a custom dns. I had it running on elastic beanstalk but due to elastic beanstalk wanting me to setup a load balancer and two EC2's just to have a custom DNS, I decided to give lightsail container services a try. However.....

I created my container, deployed and it worked fine. I can access the public domain but for some reason, google has marked my website as dangerous? This wasn't the case on elastic beanstalk.

I then tried to create my custom domain. So I registered a domain name on Route 53 i.e. test.com, created the certificate on lightsail and then went back to route 53 to add a new cname record. The lightsail status changed to "Status:Valid, in use"

But my custom domain does not redirect to the public domain at all, I just get "This site can’t be reached" when navigating to "test.com" (not my real dns name)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the below steps:-

```
1. Create a certificate with CNAME.

2. Add your Name and value in the R53 Hosted zone that will validate your certificate.


3. Now Choose a certificate to validate your custom domain.
```